# Exception in "helloworld" server and client program in socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

I am getting this error when I'm running my client program. I was unable to recognise the problem yet.I've changed the port numbers but there is no use. I saw the previous posts regarding the same error but I didn't figured it out.

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class Server{

 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
 {

   String clientSentence;
   String capitalizedSentence;
   ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);

   while (true) 
   {
      Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
       BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new 
      InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
       DataOutputStream outToClient = new 
       DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
       clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
         outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
     }
  }
  }
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
 {
      String sentence;
      String modifiedSentence;
      BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);    
      DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
      outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
      modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
      System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
      clientSocket.close();
 }
 }
```

I am getting an error when I run the client.java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Client.main(Client.java:11)
```

Can anyone help with this error?

Comment: When it's a question you use a question mark not three exclamation marks

Comment: You open both of your sockets on the same port.

Comment: Yes, I used the same port.

Comment: Use other port than 8080.

Comment: I guess the server is started before the client, right?

Comment: I started the server first.@Rainer

Comment: I've checked for other ports also but same exception is repeating. @Enzokie

Comment: Sometimes it does not work when Antivirus Firewall is running.

Answer (score 1):

The Client and Server Program runs perfectly fine for me.

1. Can you check if there is some process already listening on that port.

Comment: Was about to say the same. Copy&Past --> Works just fine. Under Windows you can use the "netstat" cmd line tool to check if the port is used. With "-b" it will even tell you which application (requires admin privileges)

Comment: No, I've checked

Comment: I am getting "The requested operation requires elevation." when I am using <netstat -b> @Rainer

Comment: Can you check again if your server program is indeed running. I guess server program is not even starting in your case. When i terminated my server program and then ran the client, I got the same stack as yours.

Comment: When I run my server program there is no response it is running still... @piy26

Comment: @Princess: I wrote "requires admin privileges"... start cmd with admin privileges ("Start as admin") and it will work

Comment: It worked! but no process is listening with the same port number. @Rainer

Comment: Maybe some wired hosts error. have you tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?